# I can't solve it about Tensorflow, please let me know what is wrong

Tags: tensorflow

I can't solve it about Tensorflow, please let me know what is wrong...

while I studying basic tensorflow, I got a problem. but it's so weired...

other guys can run it but only me, I can't run it because of error

there are some code I learned and error message.  Please let me know what is wrong and how can i pix it.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = {1, 2, 3}
y = {1, 2, 3}
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1, 1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1, 1))

hx = w*x + b
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hx-y))
learning_rate = tf.Variable(0.1)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(2001):
    sess.run(train)

    if i%20 == 0:
        print(sess.run(cost), sess.run(w), sess.run(b))

sess.close()
```

---

TypeError: Expected float32, got {1, 2, 3} of type 'set' instead.

Answer (score 0):

x,y should be of type array/list not set. Use following,

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

Hope this helps.